# Is it safe to convert Core Storage partition to HFS+?

Tags: disk-utility, partition, core-storage, hfs+

I just got my new Macbook Pro, I tried to make two new partitions using Disk Utility but I could only create one. After googling I found out that I can't create more than one additional partition in the CoreStorage and I need to revert it back to HFS+ in order to do that.

So, is it safe to Convert from CoreStorage to HFS+? What is the advantages/disadvantages of CoreStorage over HFS+?

And in case I converted CoreStorage to HFS+, can I convert back to CoreStorage if I needed to?